# How to route with anchor in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5

after post form i need to insert anchor #thanks into link.

```
<form action="/order/<?= $item->id ?>#spasibo">
```

How to route this link with anchor?

```
Route::post('/order/{item}', 'ItemController@postOrder');
```

It get error because Laravel pass anchor accord to variable.

I try.

```
Route::post('/order/{item}."#thanks"', 'ItemController@postOrder');
```

But it does not work.

Comment: I believe this must be done in the redirect part, `return Redirect::to(route('myroute', $item) .'#thanks')`

Comment: Yes. It was hosting error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
 Route::post('/order/{item}."#thanks"', 'ItemController@postOrder');
```

> Try this:

```
Route::post('/order/{item}'."#thanks", 'ItemController@postOrder');
```

i think you are misuse of concatenation in your routes hope it helps